# Python - skip empty lines and print 3 lines after a match

Tags: python, skip

I cannot seem to skip the empty line-

```
import re  

with open('list.txt', 'r+') as f:
      line = f.readline()
      while(line):
        if line != ['']: 
            if " win" in line:
                print(f.readline(),end="")
            # 2nd line
                print(f.readline(),end="")
            # 3rd line
                print(f.readline(),end="")
            line = f.readline()
```

list.txt

```
You tell yourself...
That should have been my big win.

It's a kick in the gut. 
Knowing in your heart the reason.
While you're stuck on the outside.
Grinning.
```

It prints with like below instead-
Lines shows up after an empty line.

`It's a kick in the gut. 
    Knowing in your heart the reason.`

Comment: What are you trying to do? print the 3 non-empty lines after the match?

Comment: yes, 3 non-empty lines after the match

Comment: A line can appear empty, but every line you get this way ends in a newline. You need to strip (`str.rstrip()` should suffice) your lines before checking for content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell it to skip blank lines when printing (comments are inline):

```
if " win" in line:
    for _ in range(3):  # do three times
        line = f.readline()  # get next line
        # skip blank lines
        while not line.strip():
            line = f.readline()
        # Print the non-blank line
        print(line, end="")
line = f.readline()
```

Comment: I made an edit... I assume your "blank line" isn't truly blank => `strip()` will allow it to match whitespace only lines as well.

Comment: yes.... while not line.strip():   .... seems to have solved it. Thank you.